# Помогоите пожалуйста реализовать алгоритм на си

Tags: c, алгоритм

Задание: в строку подается начальное слово(`word`), затем подается цепочка слов(`words`, столбиком, в строку заполняется до первого пробела), по главному слову построить самаую длинную цепочку из words. Слова подбираются так: по последний букве предыдущего слова, слова не должны повторяться.
Я понимаю что тут алгоритм с полным перебором с возратом + метод ветвей и границ.
Я написала функцию поиска в слова в строке, "удаление" слова в строке если есть оно(путем перезаписи), создала матрицу где хранитсяс( первая буква, последняя, само слово(words))
Но как реализовать алгорим не пойму....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define N 100000
unsigned char matr_words[N][3][81];
char word[N], words[N], ABC_words[N];
char words_v2[N];

int find(char* word, char* words) //сам код по поиску слово word в строке words
{
    char* istr;
    istr = strstr(words, word);
    int t = istr - words;
    if (istr == NULL) return -1;
    else return t;
}
int popkf(int alllenn) { //тут по сути должен был алгоритм по нахождении цепи но вообще не понимаю как релизовывать его 
    
}

int main() {
    int wd = 0, ws = 0, kol_enter = 0, kol_strok = 0;
    scanf("%[^' ']s", word); while (getchar() != ' ');  //здесь будеть вводиться значения до пробела 
    scanf("%[^' ']s", words); while (getchar() != ' ');
    wd = strlen(words);
    ws = strlen(word);


    int slova = 0, alllenn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) {                   //здесь считается сколько слов||строк в строке words 
        if (words[i] == '\n') kol_enter++;
        kol_strok = kol_enter + 1;
        if (words[i] != '\n') slova++;
    }
    alllenn = slova + kol_enter - 1;                 //alllenn - общее число бкув + ентеров

    int sym_word = 0;                                
    for (int i = 0; i < ws; i++) {           // подсчет символов в  word 
        if (word[i] != '\n') sym_word++;
    }
    
    int n = 0;
    char* w;
    int y = find(word, words); // y - начало делитного слова
    int wdw = sym_word + 1;  //WDW(weight delite word) -
    int new_len_words = alllenn - wdw;    //new_len_words-длина без вычеркнутового слова
    if (y != -1) {   // сама функция перезаписи если функция find вернет число не равное -1 (-1 ознаяет что повторения слова в words нет) то будет перезапись в другой массив
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            words_v2[i] = words[i];
        }
        for (int i = y; i < (alllenn - wdw + 1); i++) words_v2[i] = words[i + wdw];
        for (int i = 0; i < new_len_words + 1; i++) {
            printf("%c", words_v2[i]);
        }
        w = strtok(words_v2, "\n");   // для записи матрицы matr_words 
    }
    else {
        w = strtok(words, "\n");
    }

    unsigned char matr_word[1][80];
    char b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sym_word; i++) { //последняя буква word
        b = word[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= sym_word; i++) { //заносим в матрицу последнее букву ключегового слова
        matr_word[0][0] = b;
        matr_word[0][i + 1] = word[i];
    }
    printf("\n");



    while (w != NULL) //сама запись wprds в матрицу 
    {
        matr_words[n][0][0] = w[0];
        matr_words[n][0][1] = 0;//конец строки
        matr_words[n][1][0] = w[strlen(w) - 1];
        matr_words[n][1][1] = 0; //конец строки
        strcpy(matr_words[n][2], w);
        n++;

        w = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
    
    



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Вы можете объяснить по-другому, какому правилу должна удовлетворять цепочка слов? То, что у вас написано не очень-то и осмысленно. Или просто приведите пример входных-выходных данных

Comment: @EzikBro Как игра в города: каждое следующее слово начинается с последней буквы предыдущего

Comment: @EzikBro Необходимо построить цепочку из слов максимальной длины по следующему принципу. П последней о букве с начального лова выбирается следующее слово, которое на неё начинается и так далее. Запрещено повторять слова, которые уже попали в цепочку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, C я по сути не знаю, поэтому я написал примерный код на плюсах.
Под кодом объяснение самого алгоритма.

```
void get_longest_path(vector<string>& words, vector<int>& current, vector<bool>& used, vector<int>& longest) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!used[i] && words[i].front() == words[current.back()].back())
        {
            used[i] = true;
            current.push_back(i);

            get_longest_path(words, current, used, longest);

            current.pop_back();
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

    if (current.size() > longest.size())
        longest = current;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> words; 
    string temp;
    while (cin >> temp)
        words.push_back(temp); // words[0] содержит стартовое слово

    vector<int> longest;
    vector<bool> used(words.size());
    vector<int> current;
    used[0] = true; current.push_back(0);

    get_longest_path(words, current, used, longest);
    for (auto i : longest)
        cout << words[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Окей, пусть у нас есть массив слов words (у меня стартовое слово - первое слово из этого массива, но это не важно).
Давайте заведем пустые массивы `current` и `longest`, обозначающие соответственно текущий и длиннейший путь.
Также будем использовать булев массив `used`, который для каждого слово хранит, содержится ли это слово в текущем пути.

Чтобы найти текущий путь переберем все возможные варианты путей, начинающихся со стартового слова, и выберем среди них длиннейший.
В функции `get_longest_path` мы для текущего пути пытаемся увеличить его длину с помощью еще неиспользованных слов.
Чтобы найти самый длинный путь, можно просто присваивать текущий путь длиннейшему каждый раз, когда длина текущего будет больше, но я делаю это после того, как попытался увелить путь, из-за чего мы не присваиваем новый путь каждый раз, когда он увеличивается на один.

Стоит отметить важную оптимизацию, которую вы заметили и сами: слова стоит сгруппировать по начальной букве.
Тогда вместо того, чтобы перебирать все слова каждый раз, мы в среднем случае будем перебирать только 1/26 их часть (но конечно же можно подобрать тест, в котором это совершенно не поможет).

Существует еще несколько оптимизаций, основанных на запоминании частичных результатов и использовании их в будущем. Я не уверен, что это даст большой выигрыш, но на достаточно больших блоках слов может оказаться полезным.

Comment: спасибо большое! 
сейчас начну разбираться